# Bash script, arithmetic with floating point variables / strings that represent them

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cpu, cpu-load

I'm trying to create a simple script that takes an average load **percentage** of the CPU each minute. I'm doing this by using the `sar` command from the `sysstat` package.

Here is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sar -u 1 10 | grep Average > /custom/tmp/idlefile
idleval=`awk '{print $8}' /custom/tmp/idlefile`
rm /custom/tmp/idlefile
rm -rf /custom/idlepercentage/*
touch /custom/idlepercentage/$idleval
exit 0
```

The problem is, the only thing it can do right now is output an idle percentage. I'd like it to simply output a load percentage.

I attempted to do this by:

```
loadval=100.00-`echo $idleval`
```

but it shouts at me and won't do what I ask it to do.

It seems like it wont do the basic arithmetic to do 100% - idle percent to give load percent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
loadval=$(sar -u 1 10 | awk '{print 100-$8}')
```

Comment: Works, and wow was more simple than i thought, thanks!